# How to add case insensitive sorting in react table?

Tags: reactjs

By default, react table sorting is case sensitive.

In order to make it insensitive we have to write a custom sort function.

I like this answer from https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/335.

This would help.

Comment: That's filtering, not sorting.

Answer (score 7):

For case insensitive and numbers sorting pass `sortTypes` in table props like this:

```
useTable({
    sortTypes: {
                alphanumeric: (row1, row2, columnName) => {
                    const rowOneColumn = row1.values[columnName];
                    const rowTwoColumn = row2.values[columnName];
                    if (isNaN(rowOneColumn)) {
                        return rowOneColumn.toUpperCase() >
                            rowTwoColumn.toUpperCase()
                            ? 1
                            : -1;
                    }
                    return Number(rowOneColumn) > Number(rowTwoColumn) ? 1 : -1;
                }
            }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//function to sort the results
    function filterCaseInsensitive(filter, row) {
        const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
        return (
            row[id] !== undefined ?
                String(row[id].toLowerCase()).startsWith(filter.value.toLowerCase())
            :
                true
        );
    }

    // react table code goes here
    <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        filterable
        defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) => filterCaseInsensitive(filter, row) }
    />
```

Comment: this is filtering... not really sorting

Answer (score 4):

The question mentions sorting but links to filtering. For custom sorting the app's owner mentions on `Github` to pass a `sortTypes: { alphanumeric: MyCustomFunc }` in the table props, like this:

```
useTable({
  columns,
  sortTypes: {
    alphanumeric: (row1, row2, columnName) => {
      return compareIgnoreCase(
        row1.values[columnName],
        row2.values[columnName]
      )
    },
  },
},
useSortBy
```

)

Comment: this is the good answer. The `compareIgnoreCase` function should look like this:

function compareIgnoreCase(a, b) {
    let r1 = a.toLowerCase();
    let r2 = b.toLowerCase();
    if (r1 < r2) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (r1 > r2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: You can use Intl.Collator too https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/983161

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to sort a column with react-table and with a case-insensitive approach, would be to use `sortType` on a column and then provide a custom function.

```
/**
 *
 * React Table helper to sort tables
 * with case-insensitive support
 *
 */
export const customInsensitiveCompare = (
  rowA: Row,
  rowB: Row,
  columnId: string,
  desc: boolean
) => {
  const valueA = rowA.values[columnId].toLowerCase();
  const valueB = rowB.values[columnId].toLowerCase();

  if (desc) {
    return valueA.localeCompare(valueB) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return valueB.localeCompare(valueA) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
};
```

If you do not use Typescript just remove the types and everything will work fine. Take care that we need to return only `-1` or `1` and localeCompare sometimes can return `0` or even different values according to MDN docs, that why we assign only `-1`, `1` as react-table expects.

Answer (score 0):

```
(firstRow, secondRow, accessor) => {
// get from lodash
      const firstValue = get(firstRow.values, accessor, '');
      const secondValue = get(secondRow.values, accessor, '');
      return firstValue > secondValue ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

Above is the solution I used to assign to "alphanumeric", which covered both cases. Because, as in many programming languages, strings are compared [lexicographically](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/compare-strings#:%7E:text=Lexicographical%20order%20essentially%20means%20%22dictionary,slice(1)%20.) hence we need not change the case. And even comparing with numbers works fine.